# Rewrite form attributes using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a full HTML page loaded into a string, and I need to modify all `form` according to the following.

Original HTML:

```
<form Random=Random>orignal inputs</form>
```

Desired HTML:

```
<form Method='POST' action="index.php">orignal inputs</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
<form .*?>(.*?)</form>
```

Replacement string:

```
 <form Method='POST' action="index.php">\1</form>
```

Explanation:
The first `.*?` matches zero or more of any character (except new lines), but only the minimum needed to get to '>'

`(.*?)` again matches zero or more of any character (except new lines), but only as many as needed to get to `<`, and creates a regex group which can be 'backreferenced' (http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) in your replacement string.

In the replacement string the `\1` is the backreference that refers - in this example - to the 'original inputs'.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of task you can try the [Crawler component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) of the Symfony framework.
It can help you navigate the DOM and set the properties of nodes.

The correct way is to manage the DOM tree using the [dedicated classes provided by PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

The Crawler component is an helper library that can facilitate the operations.